# Print the element of structure with arrow notation in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i have a struture with a pointer..I am just wandering how can i print the value of a structure with pointer so i wrote a code like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Books
{
   char  title[0];
} Book,*andi;


int main( )
{
   Book book;
   Book *andi;
   strcpy(book.title, "avi");
   printf( "Book title : %s\n", andi->title);
   return 0;
}
```

When i tried this code it didnt gives me an error but produces a null result instead of `"avi"`..Can you tell me why this is happening ??..

Any help would be great ..Thanx

Comment: Why do you expect it to print `"avi"`?

Comment: An array index of `0` is not allowed in C. You can use a flexible array member instead, but that would not make sense here either. `strcpy` here invokes _undefined behaviour_.

Answer (score 5):

You have to initialize pointer `andi`. For example try the following

```
int main( )
{
   Book book;
   Book *andi = &book;
   strcpy(book.title, "avi");
   printf( "Book title : %s\n", andi->title);
   return 0;
}
```

And the array shall not have the zero size. Change the structure definition at least like

```
typedef struct Books
{
   char  title[10];
} Book,*andi;
```

Also it is not a good idea to name a variable the same way as a typedef name. Though this code is valid

```
andi andi = &book;
```

nevertheless it would be better to name the corresponding typedef for example the following way

```
typedef struct Books
{
   char  title[10];
} Book,*PBook;
```

In this case you could write

```
PBook andi = &book;
```

Comment: @babx pox If you did as I described then you will get the string outputed.

Comment: @babx pox It might be that the console window is closed quickly. In this case you should provide a delay inserting something ;like getchar(); at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2):

You have not assigned anything to the pointer "andi". 
Assign the address of variable book to this pointer and then print it.

```
 Book book;
 Book *andi = &book;
```

As well increase the array size of title large enough to hold the value being assigned.